# Location of WPF control in window?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there a way to get the current rendered location of a WPF control its window *after* all of the current `RenderTransform`s have been applied?  I may just be blind, but I'm not seeing an obvious method.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess I should have kept poking before asking ... but instead of deleting maybe this will help someone later.

The trick is to transform the point (0,0) from the control's axes to the axes of the window, so...

`Point renderedLocation = theControl.TranslatePoint(new Point(0,0), theWindow);`

If you need an interior point on the control it works similar, just use that local point instead of (0,0).

Don't try basing it off of `Margin` or `Padding`, it doesn't come out correctly.

Comment: Nothing wrong with answering your own question if you find the answer. Plus, you should Make it the accepted answer. That way people who search will see it answered.

Comment: Could you perhaps come with a full example that shows how you use this?